How to set ordering between Sprites and Images?
Assume that you have an Empty Object, which holds a Canvas. This canvas has 2 Image component, Background and ScoreUI. Background is just an image for background, a nice picture. ScoreUI is aimed to show current score, time left etc. It is placed at top of the Background.
In this game, I instantiate lots of GameObjects, from a single prefab. This prefab has a sprite, naturally. That game object spawns outside of the camera, particularly at Y axis, above the ScoreUI. So when it is spawning to the map, it should be under ScoreUI, but on Background. To more precise, think of it as rain. Rain starts very above from the screen, and drops to maps in a stable road moving on Y axis. Obviously, it shouldn't be shown on ScoreUI, but should be on Background itself. Therefore, when rain moves in the ScoreUI area, it shouldn't be visible.
I searched for it, and learned about Sorting Layers, but it does not work on this problem because "as official Unity YT video" introduces, it is for Sprites. However, I need to set the order within different types.
Any help? I am sure this is a basic issue, but your one line comment probably can save me a day. Thanks in advance.
Note: I tried adding Sprite Group to Images to provide Sorting Layer attribute. Did not work. I tried ScoreUI Z axis to be 10, while others are Z=0, did not work. I tried to change the Render Mode of Canvas to World Space (previously, it was Screen Space - Camera) as suggested in this answer Another GameDev.StackExchange Question, it did not work.

Don't set up your project this way in the first place. Use UI for stuff that draws over everything — the background image that you want to draw behind game objects in the world should not be in the UI.

I see. I guess you are also suggesting that ScoreUI should be a sprite also, instead of Image, since I will modify its components, text and stuff during game?

No, I did not say anything about modifying content during play. If the score UI draws on top of other game content, it makes sense to put it in the UI system.

No, it is already in UI system. What I meant is that, ScoreUI will holds other texts and sprites on it (Example, on ScoreUI, I will place a Heart sprite, and that Heart sprite will have a little text at right corner of it, indicating remaining lives.). That was what I was trying to say, sorry I was not that clear.

Use an Image component for icons that appear in a UI canvas, not a SpriteRenderer. SpriteRenderers are for drawing sprites that do not live in a UI canvas.

Really confused at that point. Why?

SpriteRenderer predates the UI system. It uses the normal 3D world rendering system that meshes use, according to the camera perspective. Later, the UI system was added with its own rendering approach that's suited to the needs of menus and HUDs, built around the notion of a Canvas that contains the elements to layer to build the UI, and RectTransforms to help flexibly scale to different window sizes. The Image component was added as part of the UI system, as a way to draw images within this Canvas approach. Image components work with Canvas and RectTransforms; SpriteRenderers do not.

Oh, I understand. You may saved my future interview with that :D Thanks!

For UI elements like your score, you should use elements like TextMeshPro (Rightclick hierachy > UI > Text - TextMeshPro

You can change the text with a reference to the TextMeshProUGUI object and adding using TMPro; at top of a script.
For any real objects in your game that should move when your camera moves, you add a sprite renderer to the game object.

The Sprite renderer has a order in layer property. Setting this to higher values means sprite is on top of others, lower means it is covered by other sprites. If the order in layer is same for two sprites, it is pretty much random i think. You can also change the transform.position.z, but I would not do that because it can be invisible sometimes due to it being behind the camera.

"I would not do that because it can be invisible sometimes due to it being behind the camera." This advice looks odd to me. You can just position your camera and world objects so that the things you want to see are in front of the camera. Note that this answer currently does not say how to get the sprites to render in front of the background (as the question says, order in layer and z position aren't doing the job).

My understanding is, this is all handled by their position in the Hierarchy window.
The lower an item (Image or Sprite) is in the hierarchy, the closer to the camera it is.

This is not accurate. UI elements like Image components within a canvas are drawn in hierarchy order, but SpriteRenderers are not UI elements. They're drawn as part of the 3D world, according to their pivot point's distance from the camera in world space (and the sorting mode settings).

@dewbacca Yes, but you do not make your Canvas a parent for your literal game objects. Therefore, this is not a valid solution.
